# React NavBar can't align items to the right side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to split navigation items and align them to left and right. How should I change the code? I'm using bootstrap, so why navbar-right property doesn't work?

```
render() {
    return (
      <nav style={{ position: relative, top: -40px }}>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Dribbble Clone</Link>
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li className="nav-item">
              Blog
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              Podcast
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              Meetups
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              Jobs
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" 
            style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
            <li className="nav-item">
              Signin
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              Signup
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
```

Thank you

Comment: Your `top` property in your `style` attribute should be a string. So, `top: '-40px'`. Same thing with your `position` attribute.

Comment: @dogui Yes, thank you, that was a silly typo, but it still didn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
render{
const style = {
                margin: 0,
                top: 0,
                right: 60,
             bottom:20,
                left: 'auto',
                position: 'fixed',
            };
return(
<nav style={style}>
);
```

}

Comment: with pleasure!!